# How can I intercept flush/endl in a subclass of iostream?

Tags: c++, iostream

I want to pass a `std::ostream&` to a function which will perform some action whenever `std::endl` is passed to it.

`endl` is just `\n` followed by `flush`, but I can't simply subclass the stream and override `flush` because that method is not virtual.

How can I write an `ostream` which reacts to `endl`?

Comment: I'm more interested in *why* you want this? What is the *real* and *actual* problem you need to solve? This question is a prime example of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): You want help with *one possible* solution to an for us unknown problem.

Comment: It's a [manipulator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl), passed as an argument to operator<<. If you have your own stream class, you'll write your own insertion operator for manipulators, and can intercept it there

Comment: [`flush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush) calls [`pubsync`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pubsync) which in turn calls `sync` which you can override in subclasses.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude existing code takes an `ostream&`, new code wants to package its output in frames, frames may contain newlines but the existing code uses endl.

Comment: @Useless How? I don't see suitable virtual methods in the `ostream` documentation.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks, but I'm confused -- `pubsync` belongs to `basic_streambuf`. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @spraff I'm not sure how packaging output in frames is affected by a *flush*. Flushing will happen at random intervals regardless if it receives a `std::flush` or not. It simple causes the buffer to empty. It does not control how much gets output.

Comment: I think you can probably just output your whole frame to your normal `std::ostream` and then output a flush. Whether or not intermediate flushes happened should not affect anything except (maybe) performance.

Comment: You suggested subclassing ostream was feasible. If you do that you get to implement your own insertion operators. They're not members, but overloaded free functions. If there's a reason you can't subclass (despite suggesting it yourself), that reason should be in the question.

Comment: @spraff `std::ostream` is basically a thin wrapper around `std::streambuf`, as `ostream` has no virtual methods the usual way to customise its behaviour is to use a custom `std::streambuf` class. boost iostreams makes this a little easier.